# question about forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Ok, I have my web application with this web.config for the manage of users and roles

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="" />
 </connectionStrings>
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>


    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add
  name="SqlProvider"
  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
  connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
  applicationName="/"
  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
  enablePasswordReset="true"
  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
  requiresUniqueEmail="true"
  passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

For security reason `i can't set the connection string` in my web.config. Now i want to know if i can pass in the application the instance of the connection to the forms authentication in some way.

Note's that i don't want to set the connection string in runtime I want pass the instance of the connection

Comment: Do you want to set connection string through code?

Comment: perhaps you could store the code which returns the connection string in a dll and reference that dll in your project.

Comment: @Hasan Fahim maybe it's a option, but without write the string in the web.config. Although I want to know if it's possible that i made the connection in my code and then pass the instance to forms

Comment: Can you encrypt the connection string in the config?

Comment: @Hasan Fahim ok, but how can i pass the string connection without write in the web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class library and a class in it. This class could contain a function as follows:

```
public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = @"some string";
    sqlBuilder.Password = @"mypassword";
    sqlBuilder.UserID = @"myuserid";
    //set other properties here.

    return sqlBuilder;
}
```

Now you can reference the above class library in your project.

You could also encrypt your connection string. Refer to these articles:

- [How to Encrypt connection string in web.config](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/)
- [Encryption of Connection Strings Inside the Web.config in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webconfig.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

[Setting Membership-Profile-Role provider's connection string at runtime](http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2008/05/02/Setting-Membership-Profile-Role-providers-connection-string-at-runtime.aspx)

Comment: Hi this example it's pretty close to i want to do but how can i modify the string connection

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be a unique connection string per user, the link Davide Piras provided is the way to go.

If having an open connection string with SQL Auth details in it is the issue, you might consider simply encrypting it:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203213/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx